# ant - trying to copy to /lib/endorsed, library is not available in windows 7 to the next task

Tags: java, windows-7, ant, xalan

On Windows 7 I have an ant target that copies a xalan library into the jdk endorsed directory so that the next xslt transformation task can occur.

The first time that the ant target runs, the xslt transformation fails.  The second time it runs the jar file is already in the correct place and the xslt tranformation succeeds.

The first time that the ant target runs, it looks like the file copied successfully.  It feels like a timing issue, but I don't know what I can do to get around it.

Here is my copy task:

```
<mkdir dir="${java.home}\lib\endorsed"/>
<copy file="${basedir}\xalan.jar" tofile="${java.home}\lib\endorsed\xalan.jar"/>
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: It's not a timing issue, I added a long sleep and the problem is still happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when the XSLT task is executes, the JVM (which runs Ant itself) has already loaded classes from the endorsed directory. You would have to fork another JVM instance after having copied the xalan jar into the endorsed dir.

What are you using to run xslt? If it's the XSLT task, couldn't you just use the factory element in order to load xalan ? If it's a java task, then use the fork attribute to start the xslt processing in another JVM instance.

Comment: Thank you, that explains the mystery.  It was code that I inherited, and I didn't know that I could touch the xslt task, but I got permission to do it and everything is working great now.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Java is installed into the `Program Files` directory on Windows 7, therefore your JAVA_HOME will point somewhere inside `Program Files` directory and regular users do not have the permission to create new files in there.

Additionally adding a library to the endorsed path can have side-effects for other programs therefore you should better use the `classpath` attribute of the XSLT-Task:

```
<xslt classpath="${basedir}\xalan.jar" ... />
```